# Windows workstation unable to change password change for other accounts

Tags: group-policy, password, workstation

When I do a CTRL-ALT-DEL, then change password, on a workstation in one of my domains, it gives me the option to put in a username.

For another domain that I manage, it does not.
I assume this is a GPO setting but can't find it.  Anyone know what the setting I am missing is?